# Drop down menu in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
%p{style: "float: right;"}
= link_to "Report", blog_post, method: :Report, confirm: 'Why do you want to report?'
```

How to use a drop down menu if I want to have a pop up containing "Why do you want to report?" and a drop down menu containing the reasons under the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should add jquery-rails: https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails
Also you can follow this tutorial: http://joshhuckabee.com/jquery-rails-3

Comment: jquery-rails is included by default in Rails 3.1+

Comment: Yes i already have jquery, my problem is how to use drop down menu, how to write syntax

Answer (score 0):

You may use twitter bootstrap drop down menus.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html

Download the bootstrap-dropdown.js file and put it your assets file. 
Call dropdown by 
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()

There is also a demo about how to use that.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails view template, you need simply write iteration over menu-elements:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <% @menu_items.each do |item| %>
    <li><a href="#"><%= item.title %></a></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

then you need to add a little css/javascript magic to make this list looks like drop-down menu.
There's a plenty of tutorials about that topic, but much easier way, as was noted above, is simply to use twitter-bootstrap. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns. (you may check [this gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) to include twitter-bootstrap into your rails app)